# Почему программа выполняется не за 1 секунду, а за 4?

Tags: java, таймер, скорость

Написал программу. Программа выполняет все поставленные задачи, кроме одной: она должна выполнятся за 1 секунду, но выполняется за 4. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём причина?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main1 = new Main();
        System.out.println("Введите pin-код:");

        ArrayList list = main1.sort();
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
            if (i<list.size()-1) System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        main1.se();

    }

    public String input(){ //Ввод числа и проверка на соответствие условию
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String print = "123456789";
        char ch [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        while (print.length()>8){
            print = scanner.nextLine();
            if (print.length()>8){
                System.out.println("Введите число длиной от 1 до 8 знаков:");
            }
        }
        return print;
    }

    public String [] mass(String number){ //Разбиение числа на составные части и занесение в массив
        int ch [] = new int[number.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
        {
            ch[i] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
        }

        String [] arrStr = new String[ch.length];

        for (int i=0; i<ch.length; i++){
            arrStr[i]=ch[i]+"";
        }
        return arrStr;
    }

    public String [] arrays(String a){ //Все возможные замены каждого числа

        if (a.equals(1+"")){
            String arr[] = {1+"",2+"",4+""};
            return arr;
        }

        else if (a.equals(2+"")){
            String arr[] = {2+"",1+"",5+"",3+""};
            return arr;
        }

        else if (a.equals(3+"")){
            String arr [] = {3+"",2+"",6+""};
            return arr;
        }

        else if (a.equals(4+"")){
            String arr [] = {4+"",1+"",5+"",7+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(5+"")){
            String arr [] = {5+"",2+"",4+"",6+"",8+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(6+"")){
            String arr [] = {6+"",3+"",5+"",9+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(7+"")){
            String arr [] = {7+"",4+"",8+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(8+"")){
            String arr [] = {8+"",7+"",5+"",9+"",0+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(9+"")){
            String arr [] = {9+"",6+"",8+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else if (a.equals(0+"")){
            String arr [] = {0+"",8+""};
            return arr;
        }
        else {
            String arr [] = {0+"",8+""};
            return arr;
        }

    }

    public String [] merger (String [] arr, String [] arr2){

        String mass [] = new  String[arr.length*arr2.length];

        int b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<arr2.length;j++){
                mass[b]= arr[i]+arr2[j];
                b++;
            }
        }

        return mass;
    }

    public String [] combinations(String [] arr){ //Составление комбинаций чисел (возможных pin-кодов)

        String arrStr [] = new String[arr.length];
        for (int i=0; i<arrStr.length; i++){
            arrStr[i]=arr[i]+"";
        }

            String mass1 [] = arrays(arr[0]);

        if (arr.length>7){

            String [] line = merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2])),arrays(arr[3])),arrays(arr[4])),arrays(arr[5])),arrays(arr[6])),arrays(arr[7]));
            return line;
        }

            else if (arr.length>6){

                String [] line = merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2])),arrays(arr[3])),arrays(arr[4])),arrays(arr[5])),arrays(arr[6]));
                return line;
            }

                else if (arr.length>5){

                    String [] line = merger(merger(merger(merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2])),arrays(arr[3])),arrays(arr[4])),arrays(arr[5]));
                    return line;
                }

                    else if (arr.length>4){
                        String [] line = merger(merger(merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2])),arrays(arr[3])),arrays(arr[4]));
                        return line;
                    }

                        else if (arr.length>3){
                            String [] line = merger(merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2])),arrays(arr[3]));
                            return line;
                    }
                            else if (arrStr.length>2){
                                String [] line = merger(merger(mass1,arrays(arr[1])),arrays(arr[2]));
                                return line;
                        }

                                else if (arrStr.length>1) {

                                    String[] line = merger(mass1, arrays(arr[1]));

                                    return line;
                        }


        return mass1;
    }

    public ArrayList sort(){ //Сортировка массива комбинаций
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        String [] mass = combinations(mass(input()));
        for (int i = 0; i<mass.length;i++){
            list.add(mass[i]);
        }
        Collections.sort(list);

        return list;
    }

    public void se(){
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(time);

    }
}
```

Comment: Сначала полностью перепишите код. Код просто нечитабельный, от слова "совсем". Не думаю, что кто-то будет реально разбираться в Вашей проблеме при существующем коде

Comment: Зачем все эти `1+""`, если можно писать просто `"1"`?

Comment: @insolor, рефлекторно написал, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @НиколайСеменов странный рефлекс. Это нужно очень долго и много писать код таким извращенным способом, чтобы получить такую привычку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам слово рефакторинг знакомо? Программа работает медленно из-за создания огромного количества стринговых объектов. 
Немного подправил код, он сократился в 2,5 раза.
Кроме того, убрал ненужные конкатинации, использовал джойнер для стрингов и паралельную сортировку. 
Теперь это работает в два раза быстрее, что, разумеется, не предел. Дальше уже своими силами) Удачи

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main1 = new Main();
        System.out.println("Введите pin-код:");
        String userInput = main1.input();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<String> list = main1.combinations(userInput);
        System.out.println(list);        
        System.out.println();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(time);        
    }
    public String input() { //Ввод числа и проверка на соответствие условию
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Введите число длиной от 1 до 8 знаков:");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            try {Integer.valueOf(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {continue;}
            if (input.length()>8) continue;
            return input;
        }
    }

    private String[] arrays(String a) { //Все возможные замены каждого числа
        switch (a) {
            case "1": return new String[] {"1", "2", "4"};
            case "2": return new String[] {"2", "1", "5", "3"};
            case "3": return new String[] {"3", "2", "6"};
            case "4": return new String[] {"4", "1", "5", "7"};
            case "5": return new String[] {"5", "2", "4", "6", "8"};
            case "6": return new String[] {"6", "3", "5", "9"};
            case "7": return new String[] {"7", "4", "8"};
            case "8": return new String[] {"8", "7", "5", "9", "0"};
            case "9": return new String[] {"9", "6", "8"};
            case "0": return new String[] {"0", "8"};
            default: return new String[] {"0", "8"};
        } 
    }

    private String[] merger(final String[] arr, final String[] arr2) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(arr.length*arr2.length);
        for (final String arr1 : arr) {            
            for (String arr21 : arr2) {
                list.add(String.join("", arr1,arr21));
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public List<String> combinations(String userInput) { //Составление комбинаций чисел (возможных pin-кодов)
        String[] prev = null;
        for (String s : userInput.split("")) {
            String[] mass1 = arrays(s);
            if (prev == null) {
                prev = mass1;
                continue;
            }
            prev = merger(prev, mass1);
        }
        Arrays.parallelSort(prev);
        return Arrays.asList(prev);
    }

}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Не за что! Тут не все гладко, но по крайней мере на много понятнее) Удачи